# How to define a class template for both type and values?

Tags: c++, c++17

How do I write a template class using parameter pack which can:

1. Take values as template args
2. Take itself as template arg

Something like this:

```
struct Vector

auto v1 = Vector<1,2,3>;
auto v2 = Vector<Vector<1,2>,Vector<3,4>>;
```

I can write the following to meet #1 above:

```
template<int... I>
struct Vector;
```

But I am confused about how to extend/specialise it to support #2 as well

Comment: How about `Vector<std::integral_constant<int, 1>, std::integral_constant<int, 2>,std::integral_constant<int, 3>>;` as workaround? That you can shorter with UDL to `Vector<1_c, 2_c, 3_c>`.

Comment: whats the purpose? This looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe it is possible to get `auto v2 = Vector<Vector<1,2>,Vector<3,4>>;` but unless you tell what you want to use it for an answer might be not that useful

Comment: If you got this code working - a `Vector` template that's either defined with _values_ or _types_ - I'm not sure it would be clear what could be done with such a construct.  How would you use these template parameters that might be a value and might be a type?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you use a function to build your `Vector` objects:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Vector {};

template <size_t... Dims>
auto make_vector() -> Vector<std::integral_constant<size_t, Dims>...> {
}

template <class... Ts>
auto make_vector() -> Vector<Ts...> {
}

int main()
{
    auto v1 = make_vector<1,2,3>();
    auto v2 = make_vector<decltype(v1), decltype(make_vector<4,5,6>())>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7GvY3G5We